# Strange select-case-default behavior

Tags: go, goroutine

Could someone explain me strange select-case-default behavior? If I put fmt.printf(something %v\n) in cases, it never reaches default stage and times out. But if I defer or comment printf it's ok. Screenshots: [bad code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pUDd.png)  [commented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfZ9L.png)  [defered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60rzn.png) and my code at o playground https://play.golang.org/p/FYsToHUJE43

Comment: Don't post (links to) screenshots, post the actual code, as text.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains a potential deadlock and if your non-default cases are slow enough (e.g. in case of an IO operation), it will eventually happen.

The problem is, that if a channel is closed then reading from that particular channel results in a `nil, false` pair. If both of your channels are closed, then you won't ever hit your default case, because your select will alternate between the two failed reads, resulting in an endless loop.

If you comment out the `fmt.Printf()` functions, your for loop will be so fast, that it can (but not guaranteed!) enter a loop just after you collected enough tree items, but before the `Walk()` functions close the channels thus entering the default case and breaking from the loop. I tried to give an example of a possible execution order which will finish its run below.

```
\\ t1 - thread of Walk(tree1)
\\ t2 - thread of Walk(tree2)
\\ t3 - thread of the loop

t1 > c.send()
t2 > c.send()
t3 > handle c1
t3 > handle c2
t3 > default, break
t1 > c.close()
t2 > c.close()
```

However, putting back the IO operations will slow down your for loop so much that it will have no chance of entering the select statement before the two channels would be closed, thus it sticks in an infinite loop. What happens now is something like this:

```
t1 > c.send()
t2 > c.send()
t3 > handle c1 // long IO operation
t1 > c.close()
t3 > handle c2 // long IO operation
t2 > c.close()
t3 > handle c1 with error
t3 > handle c1 with error
t3 > handle c2 with error
...
```

You should handle your break condition outside of your select statement.

Comment: Thank u sir for full answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should just check if you're done in the loop condition:

```
for i1 < 10 || i2 < 10 {
    select {
    case x, ok := <-c1:
        if ok {
            fmt.Printf("ch1->%v i= %v\n", x, i1)
            tre1[i1] = x
            i1++
        }
    case y, ok := <-c2:
        if ok {
            fmt.Printf("ch2->%v i= %v\n", y, i2)
            tre2[i2] = y
            i2++
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i ask about printf influence to my select-case, not about improving.